# error in Install previous versions of R on ubuntu

Tags: linux, r, installation

I have R 3.4.1.1 on my computer (Linux).

I want to install R version 2.14.1 since the package Rmosek does not work in newer version.

I have downloaded the R-2.14.2.tar.gz from Cran.

My problem is that I do not understand the INSTALL instructions,

It says to unpack the R sources and go to the top directory and issue the following commands:

```
./configure

make
```

I wrote the following in a terminal:

```
tar -zxvf R-2.14.2.tar.gz

cd Downloads 

cd R-2.14.2

./configure
```

It is run but finally gives the error:

```
configure: error: --with-x=yes (default) and X11 headers/libs are not available

make
```

and it gives the error:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

The file explains that If my make is not called `make', set the environment variable MAKE to
its name, and use that name throughout these instructions. I really do not know how I should do it since I am new in Linux.

Is there any other instruction with more explanation? I would be very thankful in advance for your help or guidances.

Regards,

Shima.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libx11-dev` and try again

Comment: [Appendix A Essential and useful other programs under a Unix-alike](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Essential-and-useful-other-programs-under-a-Unix_002dalike)

Comment: Hi Ben Bolker, Thanks for reply, I tried again but I still have the same error

Answer (score 16):

This is answered in detail in the R installation and administration guide, 
http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Essential-programs-and-libraries

> Unless you do not want to view graphs on-screen (or use a Mac) you
>   need ‘X11’ installed, including its headers and client libraries. For
>   recent Fedora distributions it means (at least) RPMs ‘libX11’,
>   ‘libX11-devel’, ‘libXt’ and ‘libXt-devel’. On Debian we recommend the
>   meta-package ‘xorg-dev’. If you really do not want these you will need
>   to explicitly configure R without X11, using --with-x=no.

More specifically, for Ubuntu, this means:

```
sudo apt-get install xorg-dev
```

and then proceed with compiling and installing R.

Answer (score 7):

If you have to compile R in your system and install you should have libx11-dev package installed in Ubunut.Can you check whether this package is installed or not.

Otherwise you can configure the source with this option as a work around solution only in the case if you are not going to use any GUI functionality in R.

```
./configure --with-x=no
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply, I checked the package installation shima@courant:~$ dpkg -s libx11-dev
Package: libx11-dev
Status: install ok installed
It seems that it has been installed. On the other hand, I have the new version of R in my computer but I need to install an old version. Plus, I do not know how to write =no because it is run automatically and do not ask me yes or no

Comment: --with-x=no option can be given together with configure script running command **./configure --with-x=no**

Answer (score 7):

You need to install these libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libx11-dev \
     xorg-dev \
     libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Then run:

```
./configure

make
```

And then it should work.

Good luck!